# javascript: Error passing back object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I get an error passing back an object from function to calling function.
What am I doing wrong?

```
function stStartProcessing()
{   
   var returnValue = {};
   returnValue = srGetNextRecord(); // returnValue is undefined     
}


function srGetNextRecord()
{
   var returnValue = {};
   returnValue.addressToArray = "AAA";
   returnValue.sequence = "111";
   console.log(returnValue);    // this works
   return returnValue;          
}
```

Comment: That should work. Please post a link to http://jsfiddle.net/ with an example that doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried it (adding `return returnValue` to see the value) and it was defined. Could you add more details, such as the browser you are using or some runnable test code as David suggested?

Comment: my bad. In my code (a bit more complex), I had a sequencing issue. Code should work as progarmmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a different problem in your code, since what you posted works fine.

The modified code below shows `111`.  See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/D9rmu/)

```
function stStartProcessing()
{   
   var returnValue = {};
   returnValue = srGetNextRecord(); // returnValue is undefined -- no, it's not
   console.log(returnValue.sequence); //shows 111
}


function srGetNextRecord()
{
   var returnValue = {};
   returnValue.addressToArray = "AAA";
   returnValue.sequence = "111";
   console.log(returnValue);    // this works
   return returnValue;          
}


stStartProcessing();
```

---

On a separate note, when writing JavaScript, please get into the habit of putting your opening braces on the same line—**always**.  For what you have above it won't make a difference, but if you ever do this:

```
function foo() 
{
    return
    {
       x: 1,
       y: 2
     };
}
```

horrible things will happen—a semicolon will be inserted after the word `return`, thereby killing your return value, and causing a script error.